# Browser not launching by default - Complete Action Using dialog appears

Tags: android

I have a button that goes to a URL and have enabled internet permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

However, the browser does not start in the emulator. Instead, I get a "Complete Action Using" dialog (choices: application info, application hardware preferences, call settings, process information.) I have tried the browser in the emulator and it does pull up Google, so I know the browser works on it's own. When I run it on my phone (LG Gossip Pro), the Complete Action Using dialog asks me if I want to use things like Facebook, Twitter, and other installed apps, but not the browser. The code for the button event is:

```
View.OnClickListener button2clickhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.ratenroll.com")));
    }
  };
```

Why would the browser not be launching by default in the emulator or on the phone? Is there an alternate way to make sure the browser launches by default through the manifest as I cannot locate any setting in the emulator or phone to do so? I tried Numair's suggestion and the browser is not launching. Any suggestions?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.ratenroll.com"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Hi Numair, it still asks me if I want to use something else other than the browser. I'm using my phone and the selections are basically other apps, dialing, Twitter, things like that.

Comment: You might have no of browsers installed, that's why it is asking you for the options. Because i've tested it, and it directly opens the page.

Comment: How do you mean? There is a browser, it works and I've been using it. It's in the list of Applications when I click Manage Applications (listed under All) When I look at the settings for the browser, under "Launch by default", it says "No defaults set." Could this be the problem? It doesn't show an option to change it. Thanks

Comment: I should also mention that the emulator browser will pull up Google on start but when the browser is called from the app in the emulator, it's also asks to complete the action.

Comment: Dude i've tested that on emulator. I used this intent in onClick and it redirects me to this page.

Comment: I don't doubt it. I just wonder why it's not working in Eclipse or my phone for me? Any suggestions? The "Launch by default" on my phone is greyed out and don't see how to activate that. Going into settings in the emulator, I don't even seen Browser in the list of applications yet it's available to use. Weird lol...